# Show that $B$ $\in$ $GL_{n-1}($K$)$ $\Rightarrow$ $A$ $\in$ $GL_n$($K$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $K$ be a field and **A** = $ 
 \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & A_{12} \\
 0 & B \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$  $\in$ $K^{n,n}$ and $B$ $\in$  $K^{n-1,n-1}$. Show that $A$ $\in$ $GL_n$($K$) applies if $B$ $\in$ $GL_{n-1}($K$)$.

**My thoughts and questions**: $B$ is obviously  a (n - 1) $\times$ (n - 1) matrix in the field $\mathbb{K}$. For example: For **n = 4** is $B$ a $\underbrace{3}_{4-1}$ $\times$ $\underbrace{3}_{4-1}$ matrix in the field $\mathbb{K}$.

But generally I don't understand how $A$ $\in$ $GL_n$($K$) applies if $B$ $\in$ $GL_{n-1}($K$)$.

I thought about using this lemma: Let $A$ $\in$ $K^{n,m}$ with $A$ = $
\begin{bmatrix}
A_{1} \\
A_{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$ which means that $A_{1}$ $\in$ $K^{l,m}$, $A_{2}$ $\in$ $K^{n-l,m}$.

Therefore we have that Rank(A) $\le$ Rank($A_{1}$) + Rank($A_{2}$). But it is made for  $A$ $\in$ $K^{n,m}$ and not for $A$ $\in$ $K^{n,n}$.

How do I beginn this proof? and how does  $A$ $\in$ $GL_n$($K$) applies if $B$ $\in$ $GL_{n-1}($K$)$? (I really don't why this correct). Any hints guiding me to the right direction I much appreciate.

Comment: Using Leibniz formula, It's straightforward.

Comment: @Bernard Are you referring to my example in which **n = 4**?

Comment: @Surb My main problem with this task is that I don't understand why  $A$ $\in$ $GL_n$($K$) applies if $B$ $\in$ $GL_{n-1}($K$)$ is correct at all. I hope it is understandable how I mean that.

Comment: @Kejie: Sorry, I misundertood your notations. I'll remove my comment.

Comment: @KeJie: I made an answer.

Comment: @Surb Thanks I appreaciate that a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't really need determinants to solve this one; we can work directly from the definition of $GL_m(K)$.

We need to show that

$B \in GL_{n - 1}(K) \Longrightarrow A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & A_{12} \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} \in GL_n(K); \tag 1$

that is, $A$ is invertible if $B$ is.  We recall that invertible matrices are characterized by vanishing kernel; therefore we need to show

$\ker B = \{0\} \Longrightarrow \ker A = \{0\}; \tag 2$

so let

$\vec a \in K^n; \tag 3$

we may write

$\vec a = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix}; \tag 4$

if

$\vec a \in \ker A, \tag 5$

then we have

$A \vec a = 0, \tag 6$

or

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & A_{12} \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} = 0; \tag 7$

we may also set

$\vec b = \begin{pmatrix} a_2 \\ a_3 \\ \vdots \\ a_n \end{pmatrix} \in K^{n - 1}; \tag 8$

then (7) may be written

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 & A_{12} \\ 0 & B \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vec b \end{pmatrix} = 0; \tag 9$

thus, performing the matrix-vector multiplication indicated in this equation,

$\begin{pmatrix} -a_1 + A_{12} \vec b \\ B\vec b \end{pmatrix} = 0, \tag{10}$

whence

$-a_1 + A_{12} \vec b = 0, \tag{11}$

and

$B \vec b = 0; \tag{12}$

since we assume $B \in GL_{n - 1}(K)$ we see that (12) implies

$\vec b = 0, \tag{13}$

from which (11) yields

$-a_1 = -a_1 + A_{12} \vec b = 0; \tag{14}$

we thus see from (4), (8), (11), (12), (13) and (14) that

$\vec a = 0 \Longrightarrow \ker A = 0 \Longrightarrow A \in GL_n(K). \tag{15}$

It is worth noting that the above demonstration may be "walked backwards" to show that

$A \in GL_n(K) \Longrightarrow B \in GL_{n - 1}(K) \tag{16}$

as well; we need show that

$\ker A = \{0\} \Longrightarrow \ker B = \{0\}; \tag{17}$

now if

$\vec b \in \ker B, \tag{18}$

that is,

$B \vec b = 0, \tag{19}$

then with

$a_1 = A_{12} \vec b \tag{20}$

we have

$\vec a = \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ \vec b \end{pmatrix} \tag{21}$

satisfying

$A \vec a = 0; \tag{22}$

therefore

$\vec a \in \ker A \Longrightarrow \vec a = 0 \Longrightarrow \vec b = 0 \Longrightarrow \ker B = \{0\}, \tag{23}$

whence

$B \in GL_{n - 1}(K). \tag{24}$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$
\det A=-\det B\neq0
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

The matrix $A$ is block-triangular (with square blocks). Hence $\det A$ is the product of the determinants of the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an inverse of $A$, which directly proves that $A$ is invertible:

The matrix $A$ is in upper triangular block form, so the inverse ought to be of the form
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & ?      \\
     0 & B^{-1} 
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$
By considering the product
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12}  \\
       0  & B
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & ?      \\
       0  & B^{-1}
    \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & -? + A_{12} B^{-1} \\
      0 & I_{n-1}
    \end{bmatrix},
$$
so we see that the unknown entry $?$ should be $A_{12} B^{-1}$.

We have guessed the right matrix because
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12}  \\
       0  & B
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12} B^{-1} \\
       0  & B^{-1}
    \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & I_{n-1}
    \end{bmatrix}
  = I_n
$$
and
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12} B^{-1} \\
       0  & B^{-1}
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12}  \\
       0  & B
    \end{bmatrix}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\
      0 & I_{n-1}
    \end{bmatrix}
  = I_n.
$$
This shows that $A$ is invertible with
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12}  \\
       0  & B
    \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
  = \begin{bmatrix}
      -1  & A_{12} B^{-1} \\
       0  & B^{-1}
    \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to prove that $A$ is surjective as a linear map.

Let $y \in K^n$. We need to find $x \in K^n$ such that $Ax^T=y^T$.

Since $B$ is surjective, there is $(x_2,\dots,x_n) \in K^{n-1}$ such that $B(x_2,\dots,x_n)^T=(y_2,\dots,y_n)^T$. Let $x_1 = A_{12} \cdot (x_2,\dots,x_n)-y_1$. Then $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ satisfies $Ax^T=y^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Leibniz formula :
$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak  S_n}\varepsilon(\sigma )\prod_{i=1}^n a_{i\sigma (i)}=-\sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak S_n: \sigma (1)=1}\varepsilon(\sigma )\prod_{i=2}^na_{i\sigma (i)}=-\det(B).$$